# How would you create X amount of worker threads based on user input?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, node-worker-threads

For example, a user inputs 10, and 10 worker threads are created that run a function.
I cannot figure out how to do this, i've looked at the docs and i'm blanking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so, first, you'll have to get user input (stdin), parse it and store it into a variable.

Then, you'll launch N workers with a for loop.

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const Worker = require('worker_threads')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

process.stdout.write('How many threads to start ? ')
rl.on('line', (line) => {
   // Here, line is the user input
   if(!isNaN(line)) {
       const n = Number(line)
       for(let i = 0;i < n;i++) {
          new Worker("filename")
       }
   }
   else throw Error('Input is not a valid number !')
})
```

You can document yourself on Worker threads here : https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

And on Readline here : https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html